# Is it good practice to declare non-constant static global variables in C?

Tags: c, global-variables

I have heard that non-constant global variables should be avoided when programming in C, but is it really bad practice and is it okay if the non-constant global variable is static? Does this make it more acceptable?

An example of what I'm asking would be in this [project](https://github.com/codeplea/minctest/blob/0ab58347f8ab64441f4a927e8f206c63b5a2d195/minctest.h#L76). Here the author wrote a small testing kit in C and uses global static variables to define the number of tests and fails. Is this good practice or should something like this be avoided?

Comment: It depends on context. It is good practice in single-thread/single-core applications. It is bad practice in multi-thread applications.

Comment: I would say you should try to avoid using global and static variables as it can make code much more difficult to multi-thread later, or use in any multi-threaded program. You might not always remember what code is thread-safe and not and then get spurious intermittent bugs from data races which might not show up in testing.

Comment: A static variable is only visible in the current translation unit, it can't be global by definition.

Comment: Those are _not global_. They are _local_ to that translation unit and not externally accessible.  Given that the translation unit is highly cohesive, the issues if global variables do not apply

Comment: Note that that project's test for float equality is very dubious.  Since floating point quantities have variable resolution depending on thier magnitude, testing against a differential of 0.001 makes no sense for `double` abs values > 2^12 or `float` > 10^3 (which is very low).  The test should be related to the number of digits of precision, and you'd need a different test for `float` and `double`.  Better perhaps to pass the required precision as a parameter of the test macro, so it can be done on a case by case basis, and will catch cases where too low a precision type has been used.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing is bad practice if you use it with good judgement. But globals do indeed have their drawbacks and you should not use them without a good reason.

A general problem with global variables is that they can make your code harder to test properly, because it depends on a global state. This also makes debugging harder.

And as Lundin mentioned in comments, you can get problems with race conditions in multi threaded programs. That is if two threads are writing to the same variable at the same time.

> I have heard that non-constant global variables should be avoided when programming in C

I'd like to dive a little bit deeper into the phrasing of this question. Because avoiding global variables is more important in other languages that has good ways around it that is often lacking in C.

For instance, let's get back to the problems with race conditions. Let's say you want a simple counter, like in your examples. Here is a very simple implementation for that:

```
#include<pthread.h>

int counter;
pthread_mutex_t lock;

void increaseCounter(void)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    counter++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}
```

Do note that this is using an extra global, the mutex lock.

Globals are common in C. [errno](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) is a well known variable used to check for success or failure for certain functions.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally considered good practice to minimize the usage of global variables and prefer passing necessary variables explicitly to functions when possible.
Here are some drawbacks

1. ***Overusing global variables***, even if they are static, can make code harder to understand, debug, and maintain. They can introduce hidden dependencies and make it difficult to trace where modifications occur.
2. ***Testing and Debugging***: Global variables can complicate unit testing as they introduce additional state that might impact the outcome of different functions. Isolating and testing functions becomes harder when they rely on global state.

In the provided example the author uses global constants (ltests and lfails) to track the number of tests run and the number of test failures.
The project you provided is a simple one so in this case you can use global    variables but in bigger and more complex ones you should avoid them.Instead of them use the **C structures** (structs)

Answer (score 0):

A question I often ask myself when examining code is

> Where (in code) does variable X get its value?

If your variable X is global, any function in your program can change its value; you need to examine all of your code to determine where X is set. There are probably several functions which set it.

If you somehow restrict access to X such that 90% of functions can't change it, this could make your code much more understandable! Making your global variables `static` does just that — all functions outside your current translation unit (c-file) have no direct access to it (they can still access it through a dedicated function argument though).

So I'd say definitely `static` global is better than regular `extern` global. Does it make it good? Probably not! You could still make it better by using proper information flow (function arguments and documentation).

Answer (score 0):

There are two meanings of `static` in C.  One as a storage class (when used to qualify a local variable) and the other as a *linkage specifier* when used outside of a function as used in the the project you linked.

Static linkage means that those variables are not visible outside of the translation unit in which they are declared, so they are not in fact *global* at all.  "*static global*" is in that sense an oxymoron.

If course if the translation unit is insufficiently cohesive (such as *all your code in one file*) then they are no better than true globals, or even essentially the same.

However in this case the the module is highly cohesive, and rather small and contains only external interfaces related to the test function.  So in this case I would say that it is appropriate.

That is not to say that it is always so.  Context is everything.  One issue with variables with *static storage class* (which is any function-local explicitly declared `static`, and *all* variables declared outside of a function, whether they have *static linkage* or not), is that they are not intrinsically thread-safe.  The same variable is used by all threads, but the timing and sequencing of access may be non-deterministic, the individual variable may not be atomic, and groups of related variables may not be consistent.

For a discussion in the evils of global variables and how to avoid them, take a look at Jack Ganssle's [*A Pox in Globals*](https://www.embedded.com/a-pox-on-globals/).  It related to embedded systems, but is generally applicable.  The use of variables with static linkage is in fact one of his solutions - with access functions for controlled external access where necessary (although a liw- coupling/high-cohesion design would minimise that need)